# Functions, Pigeonhole Principle Help

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, pigeonhole-principle

[Questions On Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZQ65.png)

I understand the basis of functional composition and powersets, however I'm really not sure how to go about answering these questions...

Would I use an example set? Eg {1,2} and then derive the power set?

Comment: Many people, including me, are not prone to click through.  If you won't make the question self contained, why should we bother?

Comment: Simply state it.  $|P(A)| = 2^{|A|} >  |A|$.  So by the pigeonhole principal a bijection is impossible because and injection $f:P(A) \to A$ is impossible. 2) |Sheffieldians| > 200,000, |hairs on head| < 200,000.  so f:sheifieldias to distincct hair numbers is not injective.  And so on.... And BTW, you can NEVER prove ANYTHING by giving an example.  Don't *ever* use example sets except as either a personal learning aid, or as a *COUNTER*-example.

Answer (score 1):

Just state $|X| > |Y|$ so no fuction is injective so there are two $a,b\in X; a\ne b$ where $f(a)=f(b)$.

1) $|P(A)| = 2^{|A|} > |A|$ so no $f:P(A)\to A$ is injective.

2) People have tens of thousands of hairs but no-one has more than.... say 50 thousand.  I have no idea what the population of Sheffield is but I imaging it must be more than 100,000.  100,000 > 50,000 so any $f(a) = $ number of hairs $a$ has is not injective. So there are $a,b$ in Sheifield so that $f(a)=f(b)$ and they have the same number of hairs.
etc.

3) $12$ elements of your set and $11$ posible remainders when you divide by $11$.  $12 > 11$ so.... there are two numbers $a\ne b$ with the same remainder when divided by $11$.

4)  There are $4$ pairs of numbers that add to nine: $(1,8)(2,7),(3,6)(4,5)$.  You have $5$ numbers.  $5 > 4$ so.... there are two numbers $a$ and $b$ that belong to the same pair.

====

If you didn't know the pigeon hole principal you would do number $4$ like this.

Let's try to get a set where no two numbers add to $9$. Suppose the first number in the set is $a$.  All things being equal, I might as well assume $a =1$. Let the second number be $b$.  $b$ is and not $8$ (we'd have $1+8 =9$) so assuming we don't we might as well assume $b = 6$.  $c \ne 1,6$ and *can* not be $8,3$ ($3+6=9$) so without loss of generality, we can assume $c =4$.  So $d\ne 1,6,4$ and can not be $8,3$ or $5$ might as well assume $d=2$.  So $e \ne 1,2,4,6$ and can not be $8,7,5,$ or $3$ so it can be.... wait, there's nothing left.

And THAT is the pigeon hole principal.  The moment we realize "wait, there is nothing left".

And we can *predict* that that moment is inevetable.  There are $5$ numbers in our set and there are only $4$ possible pairs that add to $9$.  We will *have* to run out of possible pairs.

We might as well point that out at the very beginning and not go through the wasted effort of trying to find $5$ numbers from only $4$ different pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For each question it suffices to write the problem in terms of $f$, $A$, $B$, and verify $|A| > |B|$.

Hint: Let $f$ map each of your $12$ integers to its remainder after division by $11$.

Hint: For the fourth question, maybe consider $A$ being the five integers you pick, and $B$ being the list of possible [unordered] pairs of integer that each sum to $9$, and $f$ mapping an integer to the unique pair in $B$ that contains it. For example, $f$ maps $3$ to the pair $(3,6)$.